# Is it possible to add PHG affiliate parameters to these new App Store launch URLs in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

To launch app page in App Store app on iOS 7, this URL format is required:

```
@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@"
```

Can you also append the affiliate ID and campaign token to this URL like this?

```
@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@&at=%@&ct=%@"
```

Or does it have to be a plain

```
@"https://itunes.apple.com/app/%@/id%@?mt=8&uo=4"
```

type URL like you do in websites? Disadvantage of this URL is it opens Safari and causes redirects.

Answer (score 2):

Try it and see; the link will either open or it won't, and if it does, and if you specify a custom campaign for testing, it will either show up in PHG or it won't.  Let us know what happens, as I'm curious myself.

Oh, and if it doesn't, please file a bug, as that seems like a useful feature, and it should be trivial for Apple to add it if they haven't already.